# How to locate Angularjs elements by using selenium - python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium

```
<button ng-if="vm.signatureRequired" ng-disabled="!vm.signature || vm.signature.length < 2" type="button" aria-hidden="true" data-ng-click="$hide();vm.isAgreement=true;" class="btn btn-default back_btn ng-scope">I Agree</button>
```

I tried `Link_Text`, `xpath`, `class`..locators 
but its throwing

> "raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: "

Comment: Show code that you've tried already

Comment: 1 ) driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-default back_btn ng-scope").click()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, your selectors (provided in comments) won't work as:

- You cannot use `find_element_by_class_name()` with compound class names
- You cannot apply `find_element_by_link_text()` to `button` elements (but `a` only)

Try to use following code and let me know if exception still occurs:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="I Agree"]').click()
```

You also might need to add some time to wait until your button become clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="I Agree"]'))).click()
```

Another way to solve `NoSuchElementException` is to check whether you r element located inside `frame`/`iframe` block. If so, you need to switch to that frame before handling target element:

```
driver.switch_to_frame('frame_name_or_id')
```